# What is the orbit of the action $\gamma \cdot z$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $$SL_2(\mathbb R)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\mid ad-bc=1\right\}$$
and $\mathbb H=\{x+iy\mid y>0\}$. 
We consider the action 
\begin{align*}
SL_2(\mathbb R)\times \mathbb H&\longrightarrow \mathbb H\\
(\gamma ,z=x+iy)&\longmapsto \gamma \cdot z=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}
\end{align*}

How can I show that this action act transitively on $\mathbb H$ ?

**My work**

$$z=\gamma \cdot i=\frac{ai+b}{c_i+d}\implies \begin{cases}x=\frac{1}{a^2+c^2}\\ y=\frac{ac+bd}{a^2+c^2}\end{cases}$$

How can I conclude that for all $z\in\mathbb H$, there is $\gamma \in SL_2(\mathbb R)$ s.t. $z=\gamma \cdot i$ ?

Comment: You've mixed up the $x$ and the $y$ in your work. It should be $$x = \frac{ac+bd}{a^2+c^2}, \quad y = \frac{1}{a^2+c^2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z=\gamma.i ={{ai+b}\over{ci+d}}$ = ${{(ai+b)(-ci+d)}\over {(ci+d)(-ci+d)}}=$
${{ac+bd}\over{c^2+d^2}}$ + ${i\over{c^2+d^2}}$.

Write $z=x+iy, y>0$, Take $d=0$, and $c=\sqrt{1/y}$, then $a=cx=x\sqrt{1/y}$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick any $a+bi\in \mathbb{H}$, with $\beta=\sqrt{b}$ and let $g=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \beta & 0 \\ 0 & \beta^{-1} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \beta & a\beta^{-1} \\ 0 & \beta^{-1} \end{pmatrix}\in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, which sends $z$ to $bz+a$. We have $g(i)=a+bi$, so that the orbit of $i$ passes through *all* points in $\mathbb{H}$. Hence the action is transitive.